# NVidia Drivers - 16.04 - Alienware 15 R2

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I have read many of the articles here already on this topic.  Many are out of date or not applicable, or I have tried them, and they simply did not work.

I have the latest Alienware 15 R2 with a 970M in it as well as a graphics amplifier with a 1080X in it.  I am intending to use the laptop as a deep learning mobile workstation as my primary dev box is not very mobile.  As a community we have documented the steps to get up and running with this here: https://github.com/ftlml/user-guides/wiki/Installing-TensorFlow-w-GPU-Support-on-Ubuntu-16.04-for-Pascal-architecture

Unfortunately the drivers are not installing properly and I receive device unclaimed and therefor can not use CUDA or CuDNN etc etc.  If there are known steps for this configuration as well as using the graphics amplifier from 16.04 I would greatly appreciate those steps.

Thanks!

Comment: *the drivers are not installing properly* Please give details.